# Is there any way to know last thread to execute in the thread pool?

Tags: java

Below Room is the class which lets threads enter and exit from a room. Orchestrate_enque_deque is the class that will help thread enter and then do the increment of synchronized variable and wait till all the thread finish.

What I am supposed to do :

The last thread to finish will call the exit handler. The exit handler will then again notify all the thread to enter to next room and again continue this until the last room.

My question :

How can I know when is the last thread executed?
    When room 0 is entered 13 threads are created. All 13 thread increment() the shared variable. Threads must wait till all the thread have finished calculation.  Now how can I know that all the thread have finished calculation.

Inside the funcition work of Orchestrate_enque_deque

```
        increase();
        System.out.println(count);

        while(roomobj.enter_room){      
            cond.await();
            System.out.println("now before signal all");
        }
```

Each thread increase and wait and is never signaled to wake up.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


class Rooms{

    int room;
    boolean enter_room = true;
    int which_room=0;

    public interface Handler{
           void onEmpty() throws InterruptedException;

    }

    public Rooms(int m){

           this.room = m;

    }

    public void enter(int i){


        System.out.println("room.enter "+ i  );
        if(which_room == i) {
            enter_room = true;
        }

    }

    public boolean exit(){


       if(room < which_room)
           return true;

       else
       {
        return false;
       }

    }

    public void setExitHandler(int i, Rooms.Handler h) throws InterruptedException {

    h.onEmpty();


    }

}



class Orchestrate_enque_deque implements Rooms.Handler{

    int count = 0;
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
    Rooms roomobj;
    int which_room = 0;
    int room_no;
    Rooms.Handler handler;

    Orchestrate_enque_deque(int room_no){
        this.room_no = room_no;
    roomobj = new Rooms(room_no);

    }

    public boolean when_to_exit(){

    return roomobj.exit();
    }

    public void increase(){

        for(int i =0;i <100;i++){

        count++;
        }
    }

    public void work() throws InterruptedException{
        lock.lock();    
    //while()
    // wait till all thread finish job in room.

        while(roomobj.enter_room == false)
        cond.await();
        roomobj.enter(which_room);
        try{

                if(which_room >0 && which_room < room_no){
                    System.out.println("orchestrate work : which_room" + which_room );
                cond.signalAll();
                }


            increase();
            System.out.println(count);

            while(roomobj.enter_room){      
                cond.await();
                System.out.println("now before signal all");
            }

            //roomobj.setExitHandler(i, h);

       }finally{
       //   roomobj.setExitHandler(i, handler);
            lock.unlock();  

       }

    }


     public void onEmpty() throws InterruptedException {


    roomobj.enter_room = false;
    which_room++;
    System.out.println("inside onEmpty : which_room after adding" + which_room);
     }


}

class Worker extends Thread{

    Orchestrate_enque_deque obj;

    public Worker(Orchestrate_enque_deque obj){
    this.obj = obj;

    }


    public void run(){
    try {

        while(!obj.when_to_exit()){
            obj.work();
            //System.out.println(" I am thread doing run with id "+Thread.currentThread().getId() );
            obj.onEmpty();
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

class Simulate{


    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    int NO_OF_THREADS = 13; 
    Orchestrate_enque_deque Orchestrate_obj = new Orchestrate_enque_deque(4);

    Worker[] worker_obj = new Worker[NO_OF_THREADS];



    for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS;i++){

        worker_obj[i] = new Worker(Orchestrate_obj);
        worker_obj[i].start();
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < NO_OF_THREADS;j++){

        worker_obj[j].join();
    }

}


}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Please fix the last sentence, and post code.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to do.  We may need to see some code.  However, this is probably something you'd have to do yourself, i.e. when a thread does the calculation, it sets something in a shared object to `Thread.currentThread()` to tell other threads that "I'm the last thread to do the calculation".  Some synchronization will probably be needed.

Comment: hey guys thank you so much for the response. I have made some changes and added the code.

Comment: you still haven't asked a question or outlined a specific problem.  What is happening?  How is it different from what you expect?

Comment: Take a look at ExecutorService.awaitTermination(). It sounds like you want to run a bunch of threads, then do something once they all complete, then move on to something else. Use an ExecutorService, start everything, then call .shutdown() followed by .awaitTermination(), and you'll continue once all tasks complete.

Comment: @user1676075 than you for the answer. I will try this.

Comment: If you think you know which thread was thr last to execute something, you are probably doing something wrong. Java provides several facilities for synchronizing tasks and threads, such as latches and phasers. Perhaps one of those is more suitable?

Comment: @all What I did is counted the number of thread and when the number of thread exceed the max thread count. I call signalall(). Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the CompletionService Api provided by in java.util.concurrent

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html